# Change color of an entire column in a ListView

Tags: c#, listview

I have three columns in a ListView, I'm wanting to change every value in the third column to a green forecolor.

Username, Email, Status

Those are my three columns, all columns are also named as seen.

I've tried something like this but failed bad, since it just adds it in the listview instead of changing the color of the third column value when it's added to the listView.

```
        var Status = new ListViewItem("Status");
        Status.SubItems[0].ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(-16711936);
        Status.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;

        Pless_ListView.Items.Add(Status);
```

I've also tried something as simple as this, still no luck.

```
Pless_ListView.Items[2].ForeColor = Color.Green;
```

I've also tried editing it where it adds the Status value to the ListView like following.

```
account.SubItems.Add(Status).ForeColor = Color.Green;
```

Still no luck with this either.

I've also tried to search and had no luck on where to find an answer for this.

EDIT:

Here is my adding to ListView Code.

```
        void ColorLvColumn(ListView lv, int columnIndex, Color color, bool foreground)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem lvi in lv.Items)
        {
            lvi.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;  // allow individual styles for subitems!
            if (columnIndex < lvi.SubItems.Count)
            {
                if (foreground) lvi.SubItems[columnIndex].ForeColor = color;
                //else lvi.SubItems[columnIndex].BackColor = color;
            }
        }
    }

    private void addAccountToPlessLV(String Username, String Password, PlessHTTP captured)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
            {
                ColorLvColumn(Pless_ListView, 2, Color.Green, true);
                ListViewItem account = new ListViewItem { Text = Username };
                account.SubItems.Add(Email);
                account.SubItems.Add(captured.Status).BackColor = Color.Green;
                Pless_ListView.Items.Add(account);
            }));
        }
        else
        {
            ColorLvColumn(Pless_ListView, 2, Color.Green, true);
            ListViewItem account = new ListViewItem { Text = Username };
            account.SubItems.Add(Email);
            account.SubItems.Add(captured.Status)
            Pless_ListView.Items.Add(account);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This set the color for each item/subitem in a column:

```
void ColorLvColumn(ListView lv, int columnIndex, Color color, bool foreground)
{
    foreach (ListViewItem lvi in lv.Items)
    {
        lvi.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;  // allow individual styles for subitems!
        if (columnIndex < lvi.SubItems.Count)
        {
            if (foreground) lvi.SubItems[columnIndex].ForeColor = color;
            else lvi.SubItems[columnIndex].BackColor = color;
        }
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
ColorLvColumn( Pless_ListView, 2, Color.Green, true);
```

**Two notes on your code:**

- I notice that you wrote: `Status.SubItems[0]` but the **third** column would be `Status.SubItems[2]`.
- And to color it you would have to add the **missing two subitems** first.

You **could** do that with a constructor:

```
ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem lvsi = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem();
lvsi.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen;
```

and add it to the `Items.SubItems` collection:

```
someItem.subItems.Addlvsi ();
```

But adding it with the `SubItems(string)` overload works just as well. Note that they must be added in order!

Note that **creating `Columns` does not create any `SubItems`**. It just creates a space where the `SubItems` can be displayed.

This means that the `ListViewItems.SubItems` are a **jagged array**!

Comment: Only problem is they items are added multi threaded so more than one instance is added to the ListView at once which is causing it to have problems. Also when testing it, It didn't change it for me.

Comment: Okay thanks that update helped me a lot, but now it seems it's coloring the background and not the actual text color. Would you advise on how to make it so it's just coloring the text color instead of the column? Much appreciated I tried to mess around with it with no luck.

Comment: Well, the function takes a bool to control the color. Did you use it? You need to call it with `true`. If you are using code of your own, please show the current version. Your original code always does (try to) color the text..

Comment: I'm using the code you provided and then added this ColorLvColumn( Pless_ListView, 2, Color.Green, true); where it adds the items to the listView. But it seems it's coloring both background and the text and when trying to get it just to color the text it wont.

Comment: Hm, that sounds truely weird. Now, strange things can happen when doing threading but even though, I don't understand how it would.. Can you do a test and put the call in a button only and see if that makes it work as it should (and as it does here)..

Comment: If you are still using threads to add to the ListView you should edit the question to show the rest, ie the part where you invke the change. Also: if you create the full item, why not set the color then..

Comment: I would move this to chat, but don't have enough reputation here. But back to this it doesn't work for me from a button. It's really strange do you by any chance have skype? We can communicate there and add the fix as a comment after?

Comment: No, I don't and frankly I'll have to go to bed soon.. It is a shame I can't move this to chat either. Please show the code to create and add the Items and I'll have another look at it in the morning.. As a sanity check you could comment out the line `else lvi.SubItems[columnIndex].BackColor = color;`..

Comment: I've added the code to my original question at the bottom if you could take a look there.

Comment: Well, you do set the __BackColor__, don't you: `account.SubItems.Add(captured.Status).BackColor = Color.Green;` ? ((Elegant if a little terse; I didn't know that syntax - always something new to learn)) - Once you correct that you won't have to call the function, of course..

Comment: How did I not notice that small error, it's from when I was doing the testing before posting a question here :) Okay so that problem is now resolved but there is another problem. The last item added to the ListView never gets colored I would want it to color them all just incase you don't fully understand what I mean here is an image. http://i.imgur.com/8dSH0GW.png

Comment: You don't use the function any longer, I hope? ((It was called before instead of after adding the new item - but replacing BackColor with ForeColor is the correct way to color the status item)) - Gotta sleep now, good luck..

Comment: Nope the old function was now removed, your code works perfect apart from it doesn't change the color of the last item added to ListView.

Comment: Not sure what to make of it. Did you add the coloring to the else (not invked) branch, too?

Comment: All resolved yet again silly mistake, I moved the code around slightly and now it adds the color, I Appreciate your solid help on this.